# Simple Mail/SMTP Server with DKIM

Tags: mail-server, smtp

I want o set on my Linux machine(Ubuntu Server 18.04) a simple email server.

I need to:

1. be able to create emails
2. be able to forward (receive in one email) and sent to others
3. Not deliver itself emails, but using an email delivery provider like SparkPost or Mailchimp

The email delivery provider requires DKIM.

I found some tutorials about mailutils, but I don't know how to create email, and add DKIM

Answer (score 1):

### hardware/mailserver Docker image

This is a solution using docker:
https://hub.docker.com/r/hardware/mailserver/

Source Repository:
https://github.com/hardware/mailserver

It's quite easy to configure and do what you need.

> **Simple and full-featured mail server as a set of multiple docker images includes :**
>
> - Postfix : a full set smtp email server
> - Dovecot : secure imap and pop3 email server
> - Rspamd : anti-spam filter with SPF, DKIM, DMARC, ARC, ratelimit and  greylisting capabilities
> - Clamav : antivirus with automatic updates and third-party signature databases
> - Zeyple : automatic GPG encryption of all your e-mails
> - Sieve : email filtering (vacation auto-responder, auto-forward...etc)
> - Fetchmail : fetch e-mails from external IMAP/POP3 server into local mailbox
> - Rainloop : web based email client
> - Postfixadmin : web based administration interface
> - Unbound: recursive caching DNS resolver with DNSSEC support
> - NSD : authoritative DNS server with DNSSEC support
> - Træfik : modern HTTP reverse proxy
> - SSL : let's encrypt with auto-renewal (SAN and wildcard certificates), custom and self-signed certificates support
> - Supporting multiple virtual domains over MySQL/PostgreSQL backend
> - Integration tests with Travis CI
> - Automated builds on DockerHub

Comment: I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this, instead of using only a link.